# Как получить доступ к элементу массива

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

У меня есть массив который выглядит следующим образом:

```
np.array([ '0 -28.935262435621514', '1 63.62401061069032', '2 27.068955469757185', '3 25.723129715500633',....])
```

Я хочу получить доступ к первому элементу массива чтобы смог записать в другой массив элементов, то есть

```
x  = [ '0', '1' , '2' , '3' ,...]
```

Возникает именно трудность как получить доступ к первому элементу такому массиву, ведь исходный массив - строки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут можно применить два способа:

1. **С применением NumPy:** используем [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize). Суть заключается в том, что сначала берётся лямбда-функция, делящая строку по пробелам и возвращающая первый элемент образованного списка. С помощью `vectorize` эта функция обрабатывает каждый элемент numpy-массива и добавляет результат в отдельный numpy-массив `first`.
2. **Без применения NumPy:** просто проходим циклом по массиву и применяем ту же функцию с разделом и взятием первого элемента с ручным добавлением в массив.

```py
import numpy as np

n = np.array(['0 -28.935262435621514', '1 63.62401061069032', '2 27.068955469757185', '3 25.723129715500633'])

# Вариант 1
first = np.vectorize(lambda s: s.split()[0])(n)

print(first)

# Вариант 2
second = []
for s in n:
  second.append(s.split()[0])
print(second)
```

Answer (score 0):

Все достаточно просто

```py
a = np.array([ '0 -28.935262435621514', '1 63.62401061069032', '2 27.068955469757185', '3 25.723129715500633'])
result = []
for _ in a:
    result.append(_.split(" ")[0])
print(result)

# out
# ['0', '1', '2', '3']
```

Буквально для каждого члена массива `a`, разбить строку по символу пробел и взять нулевой элемент, который добавить в конец списка `result`